# Is GradScaler necessary with Mixed precision training with pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nvidia, apex, torch

So going the [AMP: Automatic Mixed Precision Training](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/amp_recipe.html) tutorial for **Normal** networks, I found out that there are two versions, `Automatic` and `GradScaler`. I just want to know if it's **advisable / necessary** to use the `GradScaler` with the training becayse it is written in the document that:

> Gradient scaling helps prevent gradients with small magnitudes from flushing to zero (“underflowing”) when training with mixed precision.

```
scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()
for epoch in range(1):
    for input, target in zip(data, targets):
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            output = net(input)
            loss = loss_fn(output, target)

        scaler.scale(loss).backward()
        scaler.step(opt)
        scaler.update()
        opt.zero_grad()
```

**Also**, looking at [NVIDIA Apex Documentation for PyTorch](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/apex-pytorch-easy-mixed-precision-training/), they have used it as,

```
from apex import amp

model, optimizer = amp.initialize(model, optimizer)

loss = criterion(…)
with amp.scale_loss(loss, optimizer) as scaled_loss:
    scaled_loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

I think this is what `GradScaler` does too so I think it is a must. Can someone help me with the query here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: yes, your model may fail to converge without `GradScaler()`.

There are three basic problems with using FP16:

- Weight updates: with half precision, 1 + 0.0001 rounds to 1. `autocast()` takes care of this one.
- Vanishing gradients: with half precision, anything less than (roughly) 2e-14 rounds to 0, as opposed to single precision 2e-126. `GradScaler()` takes care of this one.
- Explosive loss: similar to the above, overflow is also much more likely with half precision. This is also managed by `autocast()` context.

Comment: I had trouble finding concrete resources on the matter, so thank you for a clear answer!